# Trouble chaining useEffects to use updated state from previous effects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, closures, use-effect

I have an application that has some complex data fetching. Overall, here is a snapshot of the logic in my application

```js
// dep1 is from redux, dep2 is local state

// useEffect 1
useEffect(() => {
   // perform some state variable update to dep2
}, [dep1]);

// useEffect 2
useEffect(() => {
   // use some values from deps to fetch data
}, [dep1, dep2]);
```

The issue I am facing is that when dep1 and/or dep2 update, the state change from useEffect 1 needs to reflect in the request url of the data fetching operation in useEffect 2. useEffect 2 ends up running twice, once with the dep1 update (without the dep2 update from useEffect 1 in the url) and once with the dep2 update. This issue is not specifically noticeable in most cases where we are just rendering, but we end up with double api fetches in cases where data fetching is used in the useEffect. What is some strategy that I can use to circumvent this double API call?

**EDIT**
Adding more code to allow more specifity for problem:

```js
// useEffect 1
// when the user is changed (user is a prop that is from redux),
// option should be reset to "DEFAULT"
useEffect(() => {
    setOption("DEFAULT");
}, [currentUser]);

// useEffect 2
// option is a value that can be set within the UI and is local state.
// setting option to a new value will trigger api call with new value
useEffect(() => {
    const data = await getData(option);
}, [currentUser, option]);
```

The issue when option is not "DEFAULT" and currentUser changes, useEffect 2 will run twice. I would like to find some logic to allow it to run once with option set back to "DEFAULT" if currentUser changed. Is this possible using other react patterns, since it doesn't seem possible with useEffect?

Comment: Either remove "dep1" as a dependency of effect2, or use a single effect. Can you update your question to include a more accurate/representative code example so we can provide more targeted/accurate help? A correct solution sort of depends on your specific use-case for what is possible and valid.

Comment: @DrewReese I've updated the question with more information as requested

Comment: What happens if you remove `currentUser` from the effect2 dependency? I don't see it as a dependency since it's not referenced in the hook callback. When `currentUser` changes it will trigger both effects (*since effect1 updates `option` to trigger effect2*). The edge case I do see though is on the initial render, both will be called and a second `getData` call will be made, so maybe add *some* condition in effect1 to update the option.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are complicating it alot. I would suggest using a single effect hook and compute the logic and perform data fetching in the same effect.

```
/ dep1 is from redux, dep2 is local state

// useEffect 1
useEffect(() => {
   // perform some state variable update to dep2
   // perform data fetching here and if you want to check some condition for dep2 you could do that here as well.

}, [dep1]);
```

Comment: This is different from my logic above, assuming I need to always update dep2 in case of dep1 update. In my logic, I want to fetch data with any change to dep1 and dep2.

Furthermore, the state update in this logic won't apply within the context of this useEffect, as the closure is using the state prior to the proposed update to dep2.

Comment: @gdkat I think "I want to fetch data with any change to dep1 and dep2" answers your question then... seems you've the correct code in place according to your pseudo-snippet.

Comment: could changing the order of useEffect work? @gdkat

Answer (score 0):

Try setting dep2 inside a react component within the current component and passing it as a prop, so that you only have one useEffect in each component, with state being passed up.

```js
const component = () => {

    useEffect(() => {
       // do something
    }, [dep1]);
    
    
    return (
           <div> <ComponentTwo depTwo={depTwo}/> </div>
    )
}
```

then in ComponentTwo ...

```js
const componentTwo = ({ depTwo }) => {

    // useEffect 2
    useEffect(() => {
       // use some values from deps to fetch data
    }, [dep2]);
    
    
    return (<div> something </div>
    
    )
}
```

You'll need to import ComponentTwo inside the parent component.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to find some logic to allow it to run once with option set back to "DEFAULT" if currentUser changed.

## Logic

Let's try to avoid updating state in either effect. If I understand the situation correctly, then logically, we are looking at *4 permutations over 2 variables treated as flags* (boolean/truthy values):

### Variables

- option - **[0**:default / **1**:**new** (user updated)**]**
- user - **[0**:existing / **1**:**new** (redux updated)**]**

### Variable State Cases

- Case 1. **[00]** Initial state     - default options, existing user
- Case 2. **[01]** User is updated   - default user, **new** user
- Case 3. **[10]** Option is updated - **new** options, existing user
- Case 4. **[11]** User & Option are updated - **new** user, **new** options

### Caveats

I assume that you won't have rendering attempts before redux sets the user prop. But if this is the case, I can updated the answer given more context on how options/api calls are expected to be handled if the user is null.

For the case of (4)(new user, new options), we handle the option state updates within the component itself via user UI inputs, and therefore cannot reach this state from a single re-render. It is effectively transitioning to [2], thanks to redux, then to [3], thanks to (and only after) user input.

Let's make sure we handle all cases, such that in each case, we only call the API once.

### Code

Assuming you have a null default option state

```
const [option, setOption] = useState(null)
```

### Case 1, Case 2

This effect will run once on the initial render, and once when currentUser is changed. [proof (react docs)](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#examples-dependencies).

```
// useEffect 1 
// when the user is changed ([currentUser] is a prop that is from redux)
// [we want to render with default options]
useEffect(() => {
    const data = await getData("DEFAULT");
}, [currentUser]);
```

### Case 3, Case 4

This effect will run once on the initial render, and once if the dependency (option) is changed.

```
// useEffect 2
// option is a value that can be set within the UI and is local state.
// If the user updates the option to a new value [we want to render with user options]
useEffect(() => {
    // to avoid two calls on the initial render, add an if statement
    if (option){
        const data = await getData(option);
    }
    // else, this is the initial render;
}, [option]);
```

### Further Reading / Explanation

Because you stated that the default option change was an effect of a change in user, it is in userEffect1 that the default option api call is made. Subsequent api calls are a result of the user updating the option through the UI, so logically, it is in the effect with the option dependency userEffect2 that subsequent api calls are made.

Since the last case (4) is just a case of handling both (2) and (3), in their separate but sequential states, we have covered all permutations over the two variables.

*We can rely on useEffect1 to retrieve the default data instead of setting the option state to "DEFAULT", assuming we do not use / require the option state to do more than fetch non-default data.*

**Note** that using null as opposed to "DEFAULT" as the default value for the option state gives us the ability to discern between an initial or new user, and an existing user choosing the default option in case the user can choose "DEFAULT" as an option.